# Are drow considered to be witches?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, witch, drow

The Witch Hunter class by Super Genius Games highlights the question of [what creatures are considered a witch](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/3rd-party-classes/super-genius-games/witch-hunter/):

> So, who or what is a witch? First, it needs to be explicitly stated
>   that “witch” refers to creatures of all genders, not solely females.
>   Second, while a GM is always welcome to rule any given creature is a
>   witch, the rules for the witch hunter class assume that “witches”
>   include:
>
> - All hags (green hags, night hags, sea hags, and any other creature who counts as a hag for purposes of creating a hag’s coven).
> - Outsiders with the native subtype.
> - Humanoids and monstrous humanoids with innate spellcasting ability (not gained from a class) that allows them to cast spells of 1st level or higher.
> - Characters with one or more levels in a class (including prestige classes) with “witch” in the title.
> - Clerics with one of the following domains: charm, death, destruction, evil, madness or trickery (and any other domains associated with evil gods, as determined by the GM).
> - Sorcerer with one of the following bloodlines: aberrant, abyssal, fey, infernal, undead (and any other domain linked with evil creatures, as determined by the GM).
> - Wizards with the necromancy specialization.

**Generally speaking, are *drow* considered witches?**

Comment: I *still* think it's awesome that when a witch hunter looks for witches it finds *itself.* (That is, witches include [c]haracters with one or more levels in a class… with 'witch' in the title"—, y'know, exactly like *witch hunter* does, for instance.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan: Funny, but that 100% nerfs the Witch Hunter's Sense Witch ability, because it always results in a positive detection. I GM-ruled in the beginning of my campaign that the witch hunter was not a witch (would often make sense thematically), but it's just as easy to say that the witch hunter is able to ignore their own "scent", or calibrate their sensitivity to sense only others.

Comment: Yeah, I *know*, and the [*last* time a witch sense question came up](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/90282/8610), I even mentioned the need for a house rule.  That doesn't stop it from being funny, though, that, by default, when there's a witch hunter, there's also *always* a witch. `:-)`

Comment: Only if it weighs the same as a duck.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Super Genius Games’ definition of “witch” states that witches include any of the following sorts of creatures:

- > All hags (green hags, night hags, sea hags, and any other creature who counts as a hag for purposes of creating a hag’s coven).

  Drow are not hags and do not count as hags for the purposes of joining hags’ covens. A drow could conceivably pick up such an ability, perhaps, but that would be unusual.
- > Outsiders with the native subtype.

  Drow are humanoids. Oddly enough, this would make a 20th-level drow monk into a witch, just as an example off the top of my head and one of the reasons I’m not wild about this product. But drow more generally, no.
- > Humanoids and monstrous humanoids with innate **spellcasting** ability (not gained from a class) that allows them to cast spells of 1st level or higher.

  (**emphasis** mine) Having spell-like abilities is **not** the same as having spellcasting ability, so drows’ spell-like abilities do not qualify them for this. This applies to creatures that say they cast spells as if they were some kind of spellcaster, for example, the [lamia matriarch](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/monstrous-humanoids/lamia/lamia-matriarch/) who “casts spells as a 6th-level sorcerer.”
- > Characters with one or more levels in a class (including prestige classes) with “witch” in the title.

  A drow is certainly welcome to take such a class, but this is not true of drow in general.
- > Clerics with one of the following domains: charm, death, destruction, evil, madness or trickery (and any other domains associated with evil gods, as determined by the GM).

  Again, a drow certainly can be such a cleric, but is not by default.
- > Sorcerer with one of the following bloodlines: aberrant, abyssal, fey, infernal, undead (and any other domain linked with evil creatures, as determined by the GM).

  Repeating myself again; drow sorcerer with the appropriate bloodline, yes; drow in general, no.
- > Wizards with the necromancy specialization.

  And one last time, not in general.

Super Genius Games does not list any other kinds of creatures as generally being witches, so no, drow are not inherently witches for the purposes of the witch hunter class according to Super Genius Games.

Comment: How about the bestiary hags? They dont have a spellcasting ability, they have spell-likes.

Comment: @ShadowKras That’s covered by a different line in the description: “All hags (green hags, night hags, sea hags, and any other creature who counts as a hag for purposes of creating a hag’s coven).”

Comment: But why arent drows covered by this: *Humanoids and monstrous humanoids with innate spellcasting ability (not gained from a class) that allows them to cast spells of 1st level or higher.*, two phrases later.

Comment: @ShadowKras Because drow don’t qualify by that definition? They have no innate spellcasting ability.

Comment: You are correct, but in that case, no examples exist (i know of undead and outsiders, but not humanoids). Doesn't it make that line irrelevant?

Comment: A few of those did exist back in 3.5: http://www.giantitp.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-136021.html

Comment: There is one from Dreamscarred Press, the Unbodied conversion to Pathfinder: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-bestiary/unbodied/

Comment: @ShadowKras Sure, it’s currently irrelevant—maybe it’s future-proofing against Paizo publishing something like that. Or some other third-party publisher. Or just a precaution against possibly having missed one, or a time-saving measure, just covering them in case any exist rather than spending time trying to determine whether or not they do. But the DSP example wouldn’t count, I’d think—innate manifesting is different from innate spellcasting. Magic–psionic transparency covers a lot of things but those are still distinct.

Comment: The [lamia matriarch](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/monstrous-humanoids/lamia/lamia-matriarch/) is an example of a monstrous humanoid with innate spellcasting abilities.

Comment: The regular lamia aswell (non-matriarch). Rokurokubi (B4) and Formian Taskmaster (B4 casts as bard) are also examples.

Comment: @ShadowKras The regular lamia appears to be an error on pfsrd, so far as I can tell—there is no entry for spells in the monster description, and the format of the so-called “spells known” actually mirrors spell-like abilities—which is exactly what the example lamia cleric 8 is statted with.